# How to change 2 different column names in a list to the same value R

Tags: r

Consider the following list

```
list_example.l <- list(data.frame(YR = 2000, MONTH = 01, CPI = 2300),
                       data.frame(YR = 2000, , GDP = 2300, MONTH = 01))
```

I want to change the `CPI` name and the `GDP` name to `TYPE`.

The problem is that the columns are not in the same order for each element in the list and the column name that needs to be changed is not the same for each element in the list.

I could do some sort of an apply function where I resort the columns so they align (e.g. `select(one_list_element, YR, MONTH, CPI/GDP)` and then rename the last column or assign it a column name vector (`colnames(one_list_element) <- c("YR", "MONTH", "TYPE")`).  But even with this solution, I would either need to select the variables using CPI or GDP explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `any_of` with `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list_example.l2 <- map(list_example.l, ~ .x %>% 
     rename_at(vars(any_of(c("CPI", "GDP"))), ~ "TYPE"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R option :

```
lapply(list_example.l, function(x) {
  names(x)[names(x) %in% c('CPI', 'GDP')] <- 'TYPE'
  x
})

#[[1]]
#    YR MONTH TYPE
#1 2000     1 2300

#[[2]]
#    YR TYPE MONTH
#1 2000 2300     1
```